# Storing multiple files generated dynamically over browser in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, recorder.js

I am using [RecorderJS](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs) in my django application. In this, multiple audio files are created in the browser. My question is how can I store these files in the server (directly from the browser).

I have got few leads like using `upload_to` in `FileField` (which can be stored via forms) or using `file-based sessions` in Django. However, I am not sure how to proceed as it seems complicated for me to combine the following reasons:

- **multiple files** to be **stored simulataneously**,
- and **storing directly from browser** (not manually uploading in the browser).

Does anyone have solution to this. Thanks in advance.

**[Update]**
I have proceeded the direction as shown below in the form of a code:

In `urls.py`

```
url(r'^audio_file/$', 'nalign_app_recorder.views.recorder'),
```

In `models.py`

```
class InputFile(models.Model):

audio_file = models.FileField(upload_to='/audio')
input_user = models.ForeignKey(User)
rec_date = models.DateTimeField('date recorded', auto_now_add=True)
```

I am sending the audio file (blob) via Ajax Jquery.

```
function uploadBlob(blob) {
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('fname', 'test.wav');
fd.append('data', blob);
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: '/audio_file/',
data: fd,
processData: false,
contentType: false,

success: function(response) {
console.log("everything worked!");
$("#audio_file").html(response);
},
error: function(obj, status, err) { alert(err); console.log(err); }

});
```

Then I receive this file in the Django view [`views.py`]. However, though the file is received but the error is generated when the `save()` method is invoked. Does anyone know the solution for this or is there any better method:

```
@csrf_exempt    
def recorder(request):
if request.method=='POST' or request.is_ajax():

    e1=InputFile() 
    e1.audio_file=request.FILES  #<-- Audio file is received here
    e1.input_user=request.user
    e1.rec_date=datetime.datetime.now()
    e1.save()   #<-- When save() method is executed, **error** is generated
   return HttpResponseRedirect(--another-page--)
return render_to_response('recorder2.html',RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: What does *storing directly from browser* means? You need to perform `POST` request to the server, you are aware of that, right? Then pass `request.FILES` to the `ModelForm` and call `.save()` method. I don't think database is the best place to store files.

Comment: @KrzysztofSzularz Exactly...how do I perform the POST request. When I put {{form}} in the HTML, I get upload button which I don't want. However, I already have the .wav in the browser, so how do I perform the POST request here. And by database I mean the server (sorry for the confusion)

Answer (score 0):

Due to security reasons browsers don't allow you to set value of `<file>` form field. (Imagine hiding this field and setting the value to some vulnerable file).

You need to [post the file via JavaScript](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/).

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of the security issue. However, I am sorry that I don't know much about JQuery. DO you know how to integrate this with Django? Do I submit directly to the server or through the forms?

Comment: This isn't Django related question. Ask separate question how to perform a POST query with file received by recorder.js. There are plenty Java Script coders ready to help you. Just tag your question appropriately.